# Lessthan(<) symbol is not allowed in jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

Have small requirement, I would like to display datatable with JSON data,
Here I have small challenge, if JSON data have special characters like `lessthan symbol(<)`, data is not displayed in the datagrid.
Dont know why it is getting problem only with `lessthan symbol(<)`
I tried with following code, please correct me if any thing got missed,
Eg:last name is `Jhons<asdf` but it showing only `Jhons`
Please help me on this.

Here is my sample code

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify([
            {
            id: 1,
            firstName: "Peter&heins",
            lastName: "Jhons<asdf"},
        {
            id: 2,
            firstName: "David>tyy",
            lastName: "Bowie<wwww"},
            {
            id: 2,
            firstName: "David<test",
            lastName: "testqwwe>qewrqwe"}
        ]),
        delay: 3
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // since we are using jQuery, you don't need to parse response
        drawTable(data);
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.firstName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lastName + "</td>"));
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hns1gr41/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hns1gr41/2/)**

You can use

```
row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lastName.replace("<","&lt") + "</td>"));
```

Instead Of

```
row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lastName + "</td>"));
```

> If you use the less than (<) or greater than (>) signs in your text, the browser might mix them with tags.
> Character entities are used to display reserved characters in HTML.

**[Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

Since < is a special character in HTML, you need to escape it.

```
row.append($("<td>").text(rowData.firstName));
```